# How to extract JSON String data?

Tags: java, json, string, gson

I have JSON string which is in a standalone Java project:

```
{"MsgType":"AB","TID":"1","ItemID":"34532136","TransactTime":1389260033223}
```

I want to extract `MsgType` from this which is `AB`

Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: have you tried anything using gson?

Comment: can it be done with gson

Comment: @Swarnajith yes it can be done with Gson, I posted one way of doing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Gson library for this.

```
            String json="{MsgType:AB,TID:1,ItemID:34532136,TransactTime:1389260033223}";
            Map jsonJavaRootObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, Map.class);
            System.out.println(jsonJavaRootObject.get("MsgType"));
```

where the jsonJavaRootObject will contain a map of keyvalues like this

```
{MsgType=AB, TID=1.0, ItemID=3.4532136E7, TransactTime=1.389260033223E12}
```

Comment: @Swarnajith please mark it as answer if you found it useful, so that it will help other people also.

Answer (score 3):

I use JSONObject under android but from Oracle docs I see its also available under javax.json package:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html

---

If you want Gson then your code should look like below (sorry not compiled/tested):

```
/*
{"MsgType":"AB","TID":"1","ItemID":"34532136","TransactTime":1389260033223}
*/

Gson gson = new Gson();

static class Data{
    String MsgType;
    String TID;
    String ItemID;
    int TransactTime;
}

Data data = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString,  Data.class);
```

Comment: +1...deserialize json data into model class is a much better way.

Answer (score 2):

I have an example with [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/):

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(yourString);
String msgType = (String) jsonObject.get("MsgType");
```

Check [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) for a complete example.

Comment: I forgot the JSONParser. Thanks @Suvonkar.

Answer (score 1):

## JsonPath

For parsing simple JSON use [JsonPath](https://code.google.com/p/json-path/)

> > JsonPath is to JSON what XPATH is to XML, a simple way to extract parts of a given document.

### Example code

```
String json = "{\"MsgType\":\"AB\",\"TID\":\"1\",\"ItemID\":\"34532136\",\"TransactTime\":1389260033223}";

String author = JsonPath.read(json, "$.MsgType");

System.out.println(author);
```

### Result

```
AB
```

### Dependency

```
'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.9.1'
```